# Container same width as parent

Tags: flutter

How to create container width same width as parent?

```
return Container(
  height:
      100, //when ListView has no constrained height; it gets an infinite height https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67778027/error-renderbox-was-not-laid-out-failed-assertion-line-1940-pos-12-hassize
  child: ListView.builder(
      //https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      //shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: entries.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
         return(Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.amber[colorCodes[index % 2]],
            child: Row(children: [
              //Center(child: Text(entries[index])),
                Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                  child: Container( //<-- make this container same width as parent
                      width: double.infinity, //doesn't work
                      child: Column(children: [
                        Text("hello"),
                        Expanded(child:
                        
                        Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                          child:
                          LinearProgressIndicator(
                            minHeight: 5,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                              value: 0.50)))
                        
                      ],
    ))),
             ])
            //child: Center(child: LinearProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,value: 20))
            ));
      }),
);
```

Terminal: Another exception was thrown: BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.

Question: how to make width row(or at least it's children) same as screenwidth? Same with columnheight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `Positioned` that only works with the `Stack` parent.
You need to make `Container` a direct child of `Row` which in the end will fill the width of its parent.

If the requirement is to use `Positioned`, then the solution is simply to put it inside `Stack` widget as previously stated.

If the requirement is, also, to make the child `Container` to be at the bottom of the `Row`, set `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` to `mainAxisAlignment` in `Row` to force the child `Container` to the bottom.

I would suggest something like this:

```
return Container(
  height: 100,
  child: ListView.builder(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
    itemCount: entries.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Container(
        height: 50,
        color: Colors.amber[colorCodes[index%2]],
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Text(entries[index]),
            Container(
              child: Column(
                children:[
                  Text("hello"),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                      child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                        minHeight: 5,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                        value: 0.50,
                      ),),),],),
            ),],),);
    },),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues here:

1. `Positioned` can only be a child of the `Stack` widget. You'll need to remove that widget.
2. You can't have a `Row` with a child of infinite width (this is what is causing your "`BoxConstraints` forces an infinite width" error. A `Row` already has an unconstrained width and will fill (or even overflow) its parent if it needs to. To make the child of a `Row` use up the entire available screen width, wrap the child in an `Expanded` widget.
3. I'm not exactly sure how you want the `Column` to take up the full screen height. It is currently wrapped in a `Container` with the `height` set to `50`. If you mean the `ListView`, removing the outermost `Container`'s `height` should do the trick. I don't see any children (at least those that aren't commented out) that should cause your `ListView` to overflow.

The video and explanations on [this page](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) may be helpful.