# ShowCase With Slidable In Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am facing Issue When Using Slidable With Flutter

Slidable Should Open and It The Showcase Should Show User
What Is Defined For Them

How I Have Called This In My Main Screen

```
if (index == 0) {
  return ShowCaseWidget(
    builder: Builder(
      builder: (context) => ShowCaseSalesTile(),
    ),
  );
}
```

ShowCaseSalesTile

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';
import 'package:loginmod/utils/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:showcaseview/showcaseview.dart';

class ShowCaseSalesTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final GlobalKey shareKey = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey printKey = GlobalKey();

  ShowCaseSalesTile({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ShowCaseSalesTile> createState() => _ShowCaseSalesTileState();
}

class _ShowCaseSalesTileState extends State<ShowCaseSalesTile> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      ShowCaseWidget.of(context)
          .startShowCase([widget.shareKey, widget.printKey]);
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Slidable(
      endActionPane: ActionPane(
        motion: const ScrollMotion(),
        children: [
          Showcase(
            key: widget.shareKey,
            title: "Share Data",
            description: "Share Bill With Others",
            child: SlidableAction(
              onPressed: (context) {},
              backgroundColor: AppColors.secondaryColor,
              foregroundColor: Colors.white,
              icon: Icons.share,
            ),
          ),
          Showcase(
            key: widget.printKey,
            title: "Print Bill",
            description: "Print Bill",
            child: SlidableAction(
              onPressed: (context) {},
              backgroundColor: AppColors.primaryColor,
              foregroundColor: Colors.white,
              icon: Icons.print,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: ListTile(title: Text("Test 1"))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error :

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during paint():
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderClipRect#af542
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1972 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: RenderBox was not laid out, Failed assertion: line 1940 pos 12: 'hasSize'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67778027/error-renderbox-was-not-laid-out-failed-assertion-line-1940-pos-12-hassize)

Comment: Nope @MendelG The Size Issue Is Because Slidable Is Not Opening